# Laravel Task Scheduler run command only once

Tags: php, laravel

Hi i know that has similar topic but mine problem is about local server (windows artisan server) When i run php artisan schedule:run the email notify runs only first time, The scheduler doesn't work locally nor  shared server.

MinuteUpdate.php

```
    public function handle()
    {

        $users = User::all();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
           
                Mail::to($user->email)->send(new CrendentialsNotify($user->name,$user->email,$user->plate));
                $this->info('Minute Update');
         
        }
    }
```

kernel.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        
        Commands\MinuteUpdate::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('minute:update')->everyMinute();
   
   
        // $schedule->command('check:reserve')->everyMinute();

    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about your shared server ? Is it on windows or Linux ? Regardds

Comment: @jascar_destin Im trying to make it work on Windows at the moment

Comment: I see, did you try to google it on how to make it work on windows ? And did you try php artisan schedule:work command ? For you local/dev environement this is the way to go

Comment: @jascar_destin
Sry i didnt knew it that must have extra settings outside of laravel environment, Ok doenst matter for local i want to shared server to run , i saw that must create Cron job that already i did it, Is it correct that commands? 

/usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/myproject/artisan schedule:run 
?
Note that the project is on subdomain!

Comment: If you're on linux, yes this command should work. You could try to run it manually in your terminal to ensure it's working as expected

Comment: @jascar_destin Can you help me with the command? i talk to the suport of shared host and they told me that must make a bash.sh i pasted this command : 
 php /home/user/domains/mysite/e-michanikos/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
But doenst run the schedule

Comment: On host support told me that the command bellow its correct but for me still doesn't schedule maybe it's something with my code /home/userid/domains/myurl/public_html/e-michanikos/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot help you troubleshooting this. Best I can do is advising you to read carefully the laravel documentation about this topic : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling
Did you try to google this ? https://www.google.com/search?q=laravel+scheduler+on+shared+hosting